# What is IDataErrorInfo.Error use for?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism-6

I'm just getting up to speed on WPF, MVVM and Prism 6. I understand how to use IDataErrorInfo but I don't know why or how you would use IDataErrorInfo.Error. In every example I've seen, it's get method returns null or a not implemented exception. It has to be in the class or you get a compile error.

What is it used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, I can tell you that this field is very useful - it's used basically to provide a tooltip about the error to the user.

for an example, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023552/how-to-use-idataerrorinfo-error-in-a-wpf-program)