# Implementing validation for all WPF TextBoxes

Tags: c#, wpf

My program has got tens of TextBoxes, which all could use one common Validation Rule. The rule itself is not very complex: it would only prevent the use of a semicolon (;).

Does there exist any way to implement it (more easily than applying the same rule manually to all TextBoxes)?

Edit: I cannot see how it could be related to [How to use IDataErrorInfo.Error in a WPF program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023552/how-to-use-idataerrorinfo-error-in-a-wpf-program) - I have no problems applying the validation to a TextBox (or displaying the error in a ToolTip).

Comment: you may consider not explicitly declaring them, but inserting them in a list. Then the validation can be applied to the whole list.

Comment: Implement your own behavior for that, just ibherit `Behavior<TextBlock>` class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use IDataErrorInfo.Error in a WPF program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023552/how-to-use-idataerrorinfo-error-in-a-wpf-program)

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom markup extension that extends `Binding` and adds the `ValidationRule`:

```
public class CustomBinding : Binding
{
    public CustomBinding(string path)
        : base(path)
    {
        this.ValidationRules.Add(new YourValidationRule())
    }
}
```

You would then use this one instead of the usual `{Binding}` when you set up your bindings in XAML, e.g.:

```
<TextBox Text="{local:CustomBinding SourceProperty}" />
```

Comment: @Alex: Did you try this?

Comment: It seems that it is impossible to create what I am asking without some additions to the XAML of the TextBoxes. This looks like to be the most simple solution, I'll give it a go. Thanks!