# How to manually fire IDataErrorInfo validation on all TabItems - MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, tabcontrol, idataerrorinfo

I am using `MVVM` pattern, my application is basically `TabControl` with 3 `TabItems` with DataGrids inside them.

I can save all data from grids to csv files and load it back. I try to add functionality that after user clicks button, a new window of string collection with all `DataGrids` validation errors pops out. I almost succeeded but I find out that I have to click through all `TabItems` to fire up their `IDateErrorInfo` property validation and gather the strings.

So my question is **how can I manually fire the validation of specific tab from code**? I tried something like jump through all tabs with `SelectedIndex` property of `TabControl` in loop firing `PropertyChanged("SelectedIndex")` each time and it changes the tab but doesn't fire validation and I get errors only from last, now visible tab.

**`EDIT`**

More details:

My every tab has its own `ViewModel` with `ObservableCollection<[TabModel]>` connected to `DataGrid`. All 3 TabModels have implemented `IDataErrorInfo` interface. Every tab has own xaml file and all these files are gathered in MainWindows.xaml's `TabControl` like this:

```
<TabControl SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedTab, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">

        <TabItem Width="auto" Header="FOO" Name="Foo">
            <Controls:Foo DataContext="{Binding FooVM}"/>
        </TabItem>
        ...
</TabControl>
```

In Foo.xaml I have simple DataGrid with columns and validation turned on on specific column, i.e.:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Id, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
```

In every TabModel I have `List<string> Errors` to which I add every result from `IDataErrorInfo` `public string this[string name]`

I try to get/do all validation from MainWindowVM's code position.

Comment: Details updated

Comment: Oh yes, didn't write this, thought it's not that important and doesn't affect the solution to this problem :x In every TabModel I have List<string> Errors to which I add every result from IDataErrorInfo `public string this[string name]`

Comment: Have a look here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023552/how-to-use-idataerrorinfo-error-in-a-wpf-program

Comment: It's not very helpful. I applied tooltip style for all my grids, the problem is to trigger validation in the first place so I can see those `(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent` from another tab.

Comment: What if you store validation error in VM? Then you don't need to rely on the UI being refreshed. Binding kicks in when UI controls are shown. If you set ItemsSource on TabControl, you won't need to set the data Context on the control.

Comment: Sorry but I really don't get you. What do you mean by "store validation error in VM"? You mean the MainWindowVM or VMs of specific tabs? "Binding kicks in when UI controls are shown"? That's my main goal in this whole thread :x So it's not that simple for me.